# Pivot table join in sql

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I Have Table Tbl_Login

```
Cat_ID int 
Amount1 decimal 
Amount2 decimal
Amount3 decimal 
dateon date


Cat_ID Amount1 Amount2 Amount3  dateon
1   10  12  12  2013-02-12 
2   10  12  12  2013-02-12 
3   10  12  12  2013-02-12 
4   10  12  12  2013-02-12 

1   20  22  22  2013-02-13 
2   20  22  22  2013-02-13 
3   20  22  22  2013-02-13 
5   20  22  22  2013-02-13 
I want To Mamber Enter Two Date 12/02/2013 15/02/2013 and

colum1  Cat_ID  12-02-2013 13-02-2013   14-02-2013  15-02-2013
Amount1 1       10      20      null        null    
Amount2 1       12      22      null        null
Amount3 1       12      22      null        null    

Amount1 2       10      20      null        null    
Amount2 2       12      22      null        null
Amount3 2       12      22      null        null    

Amount1 3       10      20      null        null    
Amount2 3       12      22      null        null
Amount3 3       12      22      null        null    

Amount1 4       10      null    null        null    
Amount2 4       12      null    null        null
Amount3 4       12      null    null        null    

Amount1 5       null        20      null        null    
Amount2 5       null        22      null        null
Amount3 5       null        22      null        null
```

Answer (score 4):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but there are several ways that you can transform this data into the result that you need.

If you are using a database that does not have a `PIVOT` function, then this can be done by using a `UNION ALL` query to unpivot the data and then use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to pivot the dates into columns.  The query will be similar to this:

```
select col, 
  cat_id,
  max(case when dateon = '2013-02-12' then value end) [2013-02-12],
  max(case when dateon = '2013-02-13' then value end) [2013-02-13],
  max(case when dateon = '2013-02-14' then value end) [2013-02-14],
  max(case when dateon = '2013-02-15' then value end) [2013-02-15]
from
(
  select cat_id, 'amount1' col, amount1 value, dateon
  from tbl_login
  where dateon >= '2013-02-12'
    and dateon <= '2013-02-15'
  union all
  select cat_id, 'amount2' col, cast(amount2 as decimal(10,2)) value, dateon
  from tbl_login
  where dateon >= '2013-02-12'
    and dateon <= '2013-02-15'
  union all
  select cat_id, 'amount3' col, cast(amount3 as decimal(10,2)) value, dateon
  from tbl_login
  where dateon >= '2013-02-12'
    and dateon <= '2013-02-15'
) src
group by col, cat_id
order by cat_id, col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b06/1)

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ or Oracle 11g+, then you can use both the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` function:

```
select col, cat_id,
  [2013-02-12], [2013-02-13], 
  [2013-02-14], [2013-02-15]
from
(
  select cat_id, dateon,
    col, value
  from
  (
    select cat_id, amount1, 
      cast(amount2 as decimal(10,2)) amount2, 
      cast(amount3 as decimal(10,2)) amount3, 
      dateon
    from tbl_login
    where dateon >= '2013-02-12'
      and dateon <= '2013-02-15'
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Amount1, Amount2, Amount3)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for dateon in ([2013-02-12], [2013-02-13], 
                 [2013-02-14], [2013-02-15])
) piv
order by cat_id, col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b06/2).

If you have an unknown number of dates that you want to convert to columns, then you can use dynamic sql (*note: dynamic code is sql server syntax*):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime

set @startdate  ='2013-02-12'
set @enddate  ='2013-02-15'

;with dates (dt) as
(
  select @startdate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dates
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) <= @enddate
)
select dt
into #temp
from dates

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), dt, 120)) 
                    from #temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT col, cat_id,' + @cols + ' 
            from
            (
              select cat_id, dateon,
                col, value
              from
              (
                select cat_id, amount1, 
                  cast(amount2 as decimal(10,2)) amount2, 
                  cast(amount3 as decimal(10,2)) amount3, 
                  dateon
                from tbl_login
                where dateon >= '''+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+'''
                  and dateon <= '''+convert(varchar(10), @enddate, 120)+'''
              ) s
              unpivot
              (
                value
                for col in (Amount1, Amount2, Amount3)
              ) unpiv
            ) src
            pivot
            (
              max(value)
              for dateon in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by cat_id, col'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b06/3)

The result of all queries is:

```
|     COL | CAT_ID | 2013-02-12 | 2013-02-13 | 2013-02-14 | 2013-02-15 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| amount1 |      1 |         10 |         20 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount2 |      1 |         12 |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount3 |      1 |         12 |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount1 |      2 |         10 |         20 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount2 |      2 |         12 |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount3 |      2 |         12 |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount1 |      3 |         10 |         20 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount2 |      3 |         12 |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount3 |      3 |         12 |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount1 |      4 |         10 |     (null) |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount2 |      4 |         12 |     (null) |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount3 |      4 |         12 |     (null) |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount1 |      5 |     (null) |         20 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount2 |      5 |     (null) |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
| amount3 |      5 |     (null) |         22 |     (null) |     (null) |
```

Comment: The type of column "amount1" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: What are the datatypes on those columns?  If decimal, what is the precision and length?

Comment: amount1 decimal(10,2),amount1 smallint

Comment: How does `amount1` have two different datatypes? Your OP shows them all as `decimal`?

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal so, wich one is it?, `amount1` is a decimal or a smallint?. If it's not `decimal`, then you should update your question with the correct information

Comment: sorry...amount1 decimal(10,2),amount2 smallint

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal then please fix your question where it says that `Amount2` is a decimal

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal If the datatypes are different, then you must `cast` the data to the same datatype prior to the `UNPIVOT`. See my edits